# How to clip content to an ellipse in a Windows Store app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, clip

I am working on a Windows Store App and would like to clip some content to an ellipse/circle. The result should look like this:

[image]

The content could be a StackPanel or Grid for example using TextBoxes or other controls.

UIElements have a Clip property but this can only be set to an RectangleGeometry and not a other shapes like ellipses.

Is this possible in XAML for Windows Store Apps?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a [`Brush` as the `Fill` of the `Ellipse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868203.aspx). I think you can also use a `WebViewBrush` possibly to paint arbitrary content.